# C# Unity script for item pick up choice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I currently have a script that instantiates 2 prefabs as GameObjects. Which have attached to them a script that the `game-object` is set active to false, then is added to my `inventory` array. Which is another script, but my issue is the other game object that wasn't selected is still there. It is supposed to be you have a choice of 2. Once you take one the other disappears. I have no idea how to do this, could anyone please help.

```
public int moralityCounter=0;
public bool Inventory;

public void Store()
{
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Good"))
    {
        moralityCounter++;
        Debug.Log(moralityCounter);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Bad"))
    {
        moralityCounter--;
        Debug.Log(moralityCounter);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: `the other game object that wasn't selected` what do you mean by that? Can you please show us your code? I don't really understand what exactly youw ant to achieve

Comment: set active to false on the other one, too

Comment: https://gyazo.com/699230cd435a48b0963cb8c4771c1ffc 
so when I take the green apple the yellow apple should go away as well

Comment: What are the positions of the apples?

Comment: Yellow Apple is X:-13.86 Y:5.36 Z:-0.3812452
Green Apple is X:12.79  Y:5.16 Z:-03812452
and this is a picture of the spawn points: https://gyazo.com/d6f4849b6827c948c82cd18b33535f9f
also, I made sure the hitboxes don't collide

Comment: Never mind I figured it out I had to change this line to match my items positions    `DeactivateCloseGoodBads(gameObject.transform.position, 10f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only the single `good` and single `bad` tagged objects, you can just set everything tagged good and bad to be inactive.

```
private void DeactivateAllGoodBads() 
{
    // Deactivate all goods
    GameObject[] goodObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Good");
    foreach (GameObject goodObject in goodObjects)
    {
        goodObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Deactivate all bads
    GameObject[] badObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Bad");
    foreach (GameObject badObject in badObjects)
    {
        badObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

public void Store()
{
    bool isGood = gameObject.CompareTag("Good");
    bool isBad = gameObject.CompareTag("Bad");
    if (isGood)
    {
        moralityCounter++;
        Debug.Log(moralityCounter);
    }

    if (isBad)
    {
        moralityCounter--;
        Debug.Log(moralityCounter);
    }

    if (isGood || isBad)
    {
        DeactivateAllGoodBads();
    }  
}
```

If there are multiple, you can do something like only disable ones closer to the Stored object than some distance.

```
private void DeactivateCloseGoodBads(Vector3 position, float maxDistance)
{
    // Deactivate close goods
    GameObject[] goodObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Good");
    foreach (GameObject goodObject in goodObjects)
    {
        // Check distance of found good
        if (Vector3.Distance(position, goodObject.transform.position) <= maxDistance) {
            goodObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // Deactivate close bads
    GameObject[] badObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Bad");
    foreach (GameObject badObject in badObjects)
    {
        // Check distance of found bad
        if (Vector3.Distance(position, badObject.transform.position) <= maxDistance) {
            badObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}

public void Store()
{
    bool isGood = gameObject.CompareTag("Good");
    bool isBad = gameObject.CompareTag("Bad");
    if (isGood)
    {
        moralityCounter++;
        Debug.Log(moralityCounter);
    }

    if (isBad)
    {
        moralityCounter--;
        Debug.Log(moralityCounter);
    }

    if (isGood || isBad) 
    {
        DeactivateCloseGoodBads(gameObject.transform.position, 10f);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am working in unity 2D and the location in the second suggestion is underlined in red and says. transform does not contain a definition for location and no accessible extension method location accepting first argument type of Transform could be found(are you missing a directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: I think he meant transform.position, there is no such thing as transform.location for unity. Try the transform.position and tell me if it works.

Comment: the code doesn't error but the second apple doesn't disappear after I take the first.

Comment: Katada, Yes, I meant transform.position. thanks. @SIGMA are you putting script this on both objects?

Comment: the second one since I will have multiple good and bad items in one scene